# Not able to add rows in grid control repositorylookupedit goes to null on cell lost focus

Tags: c#, devexpress

I am trying to add rows in grid control using DevExpress only using repository look up edit and other columns are read only.

While I am trying to select branch name after lost focus from branch name cell, cell value come to edit null value. Please see gif image.

Please Help.

[image: DevExpress Grid Control Add Row Issue]

Regards
Alyasar

Comment: Is the GridColumn.FieldName property set for the "Branch Name" column? Does the data type of this column match the data type of the RepositoryItemLookUpEdit.Value member property? What is the data source of the GridControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been solved. Just need to map Data source field and database fields.